# Use more that one nullrefer link when one is down to change

Tags: php

I have a banner script that uses http://nullrefer.com/ like in this code:

```
onclick=\'Opensite("'.$site->page_id.'","st"), PopupCenter("http://nullrefer.com/?'.$site->website.'","NameWebsite"
```

Often this site is down, I tried with others but all always is down..

How can I use a nullrefer link when it is working, but when it is not working, change to another nullrefer link?

Thank you!

Comment: `if(condition) { do something } else{ do something else }`

Comment: how can add this in my code abrove?

Comment: you tagged this as PHP. You can do the same condition in JS. Use a ternary operator; much easier.

Comment: you can give an example?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator and http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php